# c++ default argv if no parameter is parsed in console

Tags: c++, default, argv

i would like to give my file a default argv, if none is given in the console. It doesn't work cause of duplicate parameter names.
if no parameter is given, i would like to use a fixed filename in the same folder.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* argv[1]="test.ps1")
{
    std::string target = _T(argv[1]);
    std::string temp= std::string("powershell.exe -command \"")+target +std::string("\"");

ShellExecuteA(0, "runas", "powershell.exe", temp.c_str, "", SW_HIDE);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::string const default_file = "test.ps1";
  std::string file = (argc < 2) ? default_file : argv[1];

  doSomethingWithFile(file);
}
```

Comment: Didnt work:
    C:\Scripts>CreateProcess.exe "C:\Scripts\test.ps1"

    argc = 2
    argv[0] = C:\Scripts\CreateProcess.exe
    argv[1] = C:\Scripts\test.ps1
And if there is no param given:
    CreateProcess.exe
    argc = 1
    argv[0] = C:\Scripts\CreateProcess.exe

Comment: @Marabunta I don't understand what didn't work and what that text you posted is.

Comment: You made me doubt myself. I just compiled and tested it. It works.

Comment: ok actually it did work since "file" is test.ps1 while executing, but in my command i somehow have to write the fullpath to the file. how would i use GetCurrentDirectory() or anything else so i can add this to default_file?

Comment: @Marabunta c'mon this is trivial: `GetCurrentDirectory()` into a variable `path` and then concatenate `path` with `default_file`. If you still have problems, post another question, but I would suggest not giving up so easily and work on it until you manage to make it work. It is not that hard.